# Getter not working on returning Object to String

Tags: c#

Trying to call the getName() method within my program to write back to a file from a Windows Form. Name is another object called public class Name() with its own sets/gets that i can implement fine but i cannot figure out how to set my getName() to be able to call back the gets from the Student Object.

```
public class Student
{
    private Name n;
    private Address a;
    private PhoneNumber[] phones = new PhoneNumber[3];
    private Course[] c = new Course[200];

    public void setName(Name N)
    {
        n = N;
    }
    public string getName()
    {
        return n;
    }
}
```

Comment: `n` is a `Name`, so your if you want your method to return a `Name` type, you have to define it like this : `public Name getName()`

Comment: Can we see your `Name` class? Either you have to return a `Name` instead of a `string`, or call the appropiate getter from `Name` class to get the string representation of the name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Name is a class, not a string.

Either you do

```
public string getName()
{
    //Assuming name is a string property in your Name class
    return n.Name;
}
```

As sais above this assumes your Name class is made up like

```
class Name
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
}
```

or you override the .ToString() method in the Name class to return the name property.

Overriding .ToString() is explained [in MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/how-to-override-the-tostring-method)

Comment: Or change `getName` to return `Name`, or change it to an autoproperty `public Name name { get; set; }`

Comment: Thank you Cid, your recommendation of chaning it to public Name getName() solved the issue. I appreciate the help!.

Comment: @SeanBruce if so please don't forget to mark it as answer. Thanks ;)
Also, public or internal work aswell, depending on your needs